# Is it feasible to take liquid Helium in a Pressure Fed System?

Tags: rockets, propulsion, fuel, helium

Can liquid Helium be flowed through a heat exhanger to increase its temperature and pressure which will further pressurize fuel-oxidizer tanks.

Comment: If there is enough heat energy at the exchanger to produce the needed gas flow. To avoid a pump for liquid Helium the tank with the liquid should have the same pressure.